# Recursive formula in python for recursive sigma how to?

Tags: python, recursion, sum

I recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307906/ways-to-add-up-10-numbers-between-1-and-12-to-get-70-where-order-is-unimportant/307928#307928) question and got the first answer. I'm trying to put this into python code. This is what I have, but I keep getting 0 as the answer.

```
def f(n, k, s):
    ans = 0
    for j in range(1, min({k,s}) + 1):
        print j
        if (n == 1):
            if (k >= s):
                ans = ans + 1
            elif (k < s):
                ans = ans + 0
            elif (s > n):
                ans = ans + 0
        elif (n*k < s):
            ans = ans + 0
        else:
            ans = ans + f(n-1,j,s-j)
    return ans

print f(10, 12, 70)
```

What is wrong with my code? What do I need to change? I don't know what's wrong. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, `min` accepts a variable number of arguments, so instead of `min({k,s})` you can write `min(k, s)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is way too complex. You can write an almost one-to-one transcription of the answer you got on math exchange:

```
def f(n, k, s):
    if n == 1:
        return int(k >= s)
        # or: 1 if k >=s else 0 
    return sum(f(n-1, j, s-j) for j in range(1, min(k, s)+1))
    # to make it faster:
    #return sum(f(n-1, j, s-j) for j in range(1, min(k, s)+1) if n*k >= s)
```

The problem in your code is that you put the base-case checking inside the loop, when it should be outside:

```
def f(n, k, s):
    ans = 0
    if n == 1:
        return int(k >= s)

    for j in range(1, min({k,s}) + 1):
        print j
        if n*k >= s:
            ans += f(n-1,j,s-j)
    return ans
```

With both implementations I get 12660 as result for `f(10, 12, 70)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why yours doesn't work, but here's an implementation that does, which IMO is MUCH more readable:

```
from itertools import permutations


def f(n, k, s):

    if k > s:
        k = s-1

    count = 0
    sum_perms = []

    number_list = []
    for i in range(1,k):
        for j in range(1,k,i):
            number_list.append(i)

    for perm in permutations(number_list, n):
        if sum(perm) == s and perm not in sum_perms:
            sum_perms.append(perm[:])
            count += 1

    return sum_perms, count
```

It's a *lot* slower than the recursion technique though :-(

`itertools` is amazing.